How to create a JavaScript object dynamically whose value is a function
I need a method that creates a Quasar Table column definition dynamically. The method below works, however, I believe that using a for loop in place of the long switch statement is a better solution.
How do I write a for loop that produces the same result as the following:
const createTableColumns = (numberOfColumns: number) => {
  const tableCols: QTableProps["columns"] = [];
  const numberOfColumnsStr = numberOfColumns.toString();

  switch (numberOfColumnsStr) {
    case "15":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "15",
        align: "center",
        label: "15",
        field: (row) => row.fifteen.value,
        format: (val, row) =>
          row.fifteen.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`,
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "14":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "14",
        align: "center",
        label: "14",
        field: (row) => row.fourteen.value,
        format: (val, row) =>
          row.fourteen.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`,
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "13":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "13",
        align: "center",
        label: "13",
        field: (row) => row.thirteen.value,
        format: (val, row) =>
          row.thirteen.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`,
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "12":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "12",
        align: "center",
        label: "12",
        field: (row) => row.twelve.value,
        format: (val, row) =>
          row.twelve.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`,
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "11":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "11",
        align: "center",
        label: "11",
        field: (row) => row.eleven.value,
        format: (val, row) =>
          row.eleven.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`,
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "10":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "10",
        align: "center",
        label: "10",
        field: (row) => row.ten.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.ten.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "9":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "9",
        align: "center",
        label: "9",
        field: (row) => row.nine.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.nine.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "8":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "8",
        align: "center",
        label: "8",
        field: (row) => row.eight.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.eight.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "7":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "7",
        align: "center",
        label: "7",
        field: (row) => row.seven.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.seven.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "6":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "6",
        align: "center",
        label: "6",
        field: (row) => row.six.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.six.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "5":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "5",
        align: "center",
        label: "5",
        field: (row) => row.five.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.five.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "4":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "4",
        align: "center",
        label: "4",
        field: (row) => row.four.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.four.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });
    case "3":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "3",
        align: "center",
        label: "3",
        field: (row) => row.three.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.three.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });

    case "2":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "2",
        align: "center",
        label: "2",
        field: (row) => row.two.value,
        format: (val, row) => (row.two.isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      });

    case "1":
      tableCols.push({
        name: "1",
        align: "center",
        label: "1",
        field: (row) => row.name,
        format: (val, row) => `${val}`,
        sortable: false,
      });

      break;
    default:
      console.error(`Game: createTableColumns DEFAULT!!!`);
  }

  tableCols.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.name) - parseInt(b.name));
  return tableCols;
};

I've tried this:
const tableCols2: QTableProps["columns"] = [];
for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfColumns; colIndex++) {
  const rowKeyArray = [
    "NotUsed",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten",
    "eleven",
    "twelve",
    "thirteen",
    "fourteen",
    "fifteen",
  ];
  const colNumber: number = colIndex + 1;
  const rowKey: string = rowKeyArray[colIndex];
  const myObj = {
    name: colNumber.toString(),
    align: "center",
    label: colNumber.toString(),
    field: (row) => row[rowKey].value,
    format: (val, row) => (row[rowKey].isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
    sortable: false,
  };

  tableCols2.push(myObj);
}


Please limit your question to a [mre].

So you tried it. What was the result?

Thanks jessegavin.. my bad in not explaining where the problem lies with my for loop solution that fails. It's the two lines of code that start with field: and format: these need to end up as a function. And in my for loop they end up as a string like expression.

@Loren No, they're functions. Seems to work fine?

Notice that the first column has a very unusual field and format. You'd need to special-case that with some condition, or move it outside of the loop altogether.

I guess you can do a similar implementation but using objects instead:
let keyMap = {
  '1': 'one',
  '2': 'two',
  // ...
}
let colIndex: keyof typeof keyMap;
const tableCols2: QTableProps["columns"] = [];

for (colIndex in keyMap) {
  const rowKey: string = keyMap[colIndex];
  const myObj = {
    name: colIndex,
    align: "center",
    label: colIndex,
    field: (row) => row[rowKey].value,
    format: (val, row) => (row[rowKey].isSelected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
    sortable: false,
  };

  tableCols2.push(myObj);
}


To simplify matters, have a look at this (vanilla JS) potential solution:


const createTableColumns = (numberOfColumn) => {
  const englishNames = "zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen".split(',');
  if( numberOfColumn < 1 || numberOfColumn >= englishNames.length) throw("invalid number of columns: " + numberOfColumn);
  
  const tableCols = [];
  for(let col = numberOfColumn; col >= 2; col--) {
    const colAsString = col.toString();
    const colAsEnglish = englishNames[col];
    const obj = {
        name: colAsString,
        align: "center",
        label: colAsString,
        field: (row) => row[colAsEnglish].value,
        format: (val, row) => (row[colAsEnglish].isSlected ? `** ${val} **` : `${val}`),
        sortable: false,
      };
    tableCols.push(obj);
  }
  tableCols.push({
    name: "1",
    align: "center",
    label: "1",
    field: (row) => row.name,
    format: (val, row) => `${val}`,
    sortable: false,
  });

  tableCols.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.name) - parseInt(b.name));
  return tableCols;
}


// test ----------------------------------------------

const tableCols = createTableColumns(3);
const row = {
   name: "test row name",
   "one": {value: "not used", isSlected: false},
   "two": {value: "row.two column content", isSlected: true},
   "three": {value: "row.three column content", isSlected: false}
};

for( let index = 0; index < tableCols.length; ++index) {
  let colObj = tableCols.find( obj=>obj.name === (index+1).toString());
  const value = colObj.field(row);
  const string = colObj.format(value, row);
  console.log( string)
};



Note:

The code above differs from previous edits because the
the "field" and "format" methods for the column object named "1" are different from columns that follow. The fix adopted was to push column object "1" outside the loop. The code seems to run as to be expected: running the test code with the working version of createTableColumns in the post (minus Typescript additions) produced the same log output.

In the code above, the  for loop uses let and const declarations to ensure column values are in the environment record created for each iteration. Hence the colAsString and colAsEnglish values used in the function methods of obj (field and format) are particular to the loop iteration they were defined in.


Now some issues for your consideration:

Naming the row column properties with English names of numbers creates a headache and could be difficult to maintain. Using calculated column property names, say for one-based names, "C1", "C2", ... "C15", could be simpler.

The question title is a bit dubious: an object whose value is a function is a function.

The test code is known to be paranoid and finds column data by name string. At the same time it doen't check structrual vadity of the row object. It's test code only!



Thanks traktor ... my bad in not explaining where the problem lies with my for loop solution that fails.  It's these two lines of code:

field: (row) => row[colAsEnglish].value,
format: (val, row) => (row[colAsEnglish].isSlected ? ** ${val} ** : ${val}),

It seems to come out as some kind of a string expression.

As far as my title ... I agree it's not the best, but i didn't know how better to describe my problem. The output of my createTableColumns is bound to a Quasar QTable in like so :columns="tableColumns".

I found a bug in the answer - field and format are not the same across all columns. I've added a code snippet using updated code, which in testing seemed to agree with the working version in the post. Hope it helps.
